# even and odd perfect numbers existence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Thank for my previous post. Also, thank you so much for this site (m.s.e)

1) If odd perfect numbers there, those numbers can be expressible $12k + 1$ or $324k + 81$
   or $468k + 117$. If yes, please discuss, how far I am correct.

2) If $K$ = $(4^n - 2^n)$/2 is perfect, when $k = 1^3 + 3^3 + ...$

Comment: You might want to add how you came up with these results ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen! sinece even perfect numbers cannot wirtien in 12k + 1 and so on,..

Comment: Well, *even* perfect numbers surely cannot be written as $12k+1$. What was your reasoning about odd perfect numbers?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the last 'when' was intended as a 'then'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) is stated at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number), and attributed to Roberts, T (2008). "On the Form of an Odd Perfect Number". Australian Mathematical Gazette 35 (4): 244. [Here](http://www.austms.org.au/Publ/Gazette/2008/Sep08/CommsRoberts.pdf) is a direct link.

Answer (score 4):

For part 2):

The formula
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$
is well-known and leads to 
$$ 1^3+3^3+\ldots+(2m-1)^3=\sum_{k=1}^{2m}k^3-\sum_{k=1}^{m}(2k)^3\\=\frac{(2m)^2(2m+1)^2}{4}-8\cdot\frac{m^2(m+1)^2}{4}\\=m^2(2m^2-1).$$
Since it is well-known that even perfect numbers $N$ are of the form $N=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ with $p=2n+1$ an odd prime and $2^p-1$ a Mersenne prime, letting $m=2^n$, you find that indeed $$N=\frac{4^n-2^n}{2}=m^2(2m^2-1)=1^3+3^3+\ldots+(2m-1)^3.$$

Comment: ! Thank you so much for your kind help.