# Proof that an odd perfect number must be in the form $ 36k+9$ or $12k+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, perfect-numbers

I recently read [here](http://blogs.ams.org/mathgradblog/2013/07/25/odd-perfect-numbers-exist/) that an odd perfect number, if one exists, would have to be in the form $ p = 36k+9$ or $p = 12k+1$. The link says it was proven In 1953 by Touchard, but I can't seem to find the original or any other proof of this theorem. Does anybody know where I might see the proof of this?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293470/even-and-odd-perfect-numbers-existence

Comment: The article is **Touchard**, *On prime numbers and perfect numbers*,**Scripta Mathematica** 19, 35–39, (1953). You have a proof due to **Holdener**, *A theorem of Touchard on the form of odd perfect numbers*, **The American Mathematical Monthly** 109, 7 (2002), and I understand that this last article is like to elementary number theory. After as was said you have **Roberts** theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple explanation can be found at [Gazette of Australian mathem. society of Sep 2008](http://www.austms.org.au/Gazette+Volume+35+Number+4+September+2008) where you can find an article of T.Roberts